# How can the npm config module be used in angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, config

Have an application that has a angular 2 front end and node backend api that provide data for the front end. The node backend is using the npm [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) module to provide environment settings depending if the application is running on production or stage. I would like to use the same config module within the angular front end.

In node all you do to get the correct config settings is to require config

var config=require('config');

The config files also should in a /config folder of the application root where server.js is being loaded.

What is the best way to somehow require the config module into angular?

I would like to use the same config module in both angular and node environments.

Answer (score 0):

Angular (or perhaps underlying XHR) is fussy about where it will pick up files from.

Can you get the server to serve up the config file as if it were data?